# How to do Import data from Microsoft SQL server into HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have successfully installed Apache Hadoop on Cluster systems(1 Master, 2 Slaves with High configuration with Ubuntu based) using Cloudera Manager and CDH 5.4

I want to import data from Microsoft SQL server into HBase (column based hadoop database), as of now i have generated CSV file from SQL server and import CSV into HBase using HBase Browser (Hue application in Cloudera Manager).

If there is any way to directly import SQL server data into HBase it would be helpful for me, I have heard Sqoop application has done importing data from RDBMS into Hadoop system (Even i did not try this, i assume this will import CSV file into Hadoop System not in HBase)

Kindly let me know if there is any possible way for above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop does support importing data directly to HBASE by using the --hbase-table option in a sqoop command.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know

Comment: I have tried this method with smaller table working fine, i will update the command later

Comment: sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.10:1433;database=DBName;username=sa;password=password" --table "SQLCustomers" --hbase-table "HBaseCustomers" --column-family "C1" --split-by "RowNo" -- --schema admin